# Custom servlet gives 404 on Tomcat 6, works fine on 7

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7, tomcat6

In my Tomcat 7 web app, I had a servlet for private PDF files: if not logged in, forward the user to the login page; otherwise, use the default servlet to show the page.

```
@WebServlet(name="pdfServlet",urlPatterns={"/pdf/*"})
public class PDFServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (!isLoggedIn(request, response)) {
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } else {
            getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher("default").forward(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Recently, I had to transfer the website to another host which uses Tomcat 6.  I removed the `@WebServlet` annotation, which is not supported in Tomcat 6, and instead added the following to my app's `WEB-INF/web.xml`, as well as downgrading the servlet specification from 3.0 to 2.5:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
           version="2.5">
    [...]
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>pdfServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.myapp.PDFServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>pdfServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/pdf/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

However, though the forwarding still works when not logged in, I get a 404 error if the user is logged in, when the default servlet tries to serve the page.  It still works fine on my Tomcat 7 version of the site, even with the modifications to the code to make it backward-compatible; it also works fine when the PDF servlet is removed, but then it allows anyone to access the private PDFs.

Why is the default servlet not correctly serving the pages in Tomcat 6 only?

Comment: is there any error at deployment time

Comment: Not that I could see.  Where should I check?

Comment: Try to put breakpoint inside servlet. Is it caught?

Comment: @LeosLiterak I only have Tomcat 7 on the local machine I use for debugging (though I may install Tomcat 6 now).  In any case, even on Tomcat 6 the servlet correctly redirects to the login when the user is not logged in, so it is definitely being called.

Comment: Try to dispatch default servlet to some other existing static file on different path. Will it work? You can attach tomcat sources and debug tomcat as well.

Comment: @LeosLiterak Same error when trying to access images from a different directory.  I was not able to debug Tomcat, but I installed Tomcat 6 locally and verified that a breakpoint on the servlet was hit when the PDFs were accessed.  100% sure this is a version issue now since Tomcat 7 behaves differently from 6 on the same computer.

Comment: Does Tomcat 6 really support @WebServlet? Is the servlet being deployed at all? Check the logs.

Comment: Could it be possible that default servlet has different name under tomcat 6? It looks like it is not found.

Comment: Exactly same problem! As I found it works on tomcat 6.0.37 and not 6.0.29 ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in tomcat https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50026

As suggested by @1" a filter can do the job, here is how it should look:

```
public class SampleFilter implements Filter {

    FilterConfig config; //setter and getters ommited

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
            this.config=filterConfig;  
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        if (!isLoggedIn(request, response)) {
            getFilterConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } else {
           chain.doFilter(request, response); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using a [Filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) instead of a Servlet.  I am still curious about why the error occurs, though.